# Build System for LC-3 in Sublime Text 3

Tags: assembly, sublimetext3, lc3, build-system

I am trying to build LC-3 Assembly Code in Sublime Text 3 into object file (.obj) but it seems doesn't work. I found some kinds of Highlight Syntax, but there is no build system.

Are there any ways to build it in Sublime Text 3? The UI of LC3 Editor is kinda boring, and I can't stand working all day with such a monotonous UI like it.

Comment: ehmm... as the tag [tag:lc3] reads: "It is run using an emulator and doesn't run natively on any processor". What exactly are you looking for? Cross assembling from an educational purpose only architecture? O_o

Comment: If you know of some command you can run from a terminal that does what you want, you can automate it. If you have to use their IDE to do it, you're out of luck most likely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe I have to copy/paste if I want to use Sublime Text :(